# Issue with .split()

Tags: python, python-3.x

It was fixed thanks to the help here, the fixed code looks like this

```
import os
os.chdir('data')
for filename in os.listdir():
    F = open(filename, 'r+', encoding="utf8").read()
    for token in F.split():
        if 'http' in token:
            print(token.encode("utf8"))
```

Comment: What output do you expect? What do you get instead?

Comment: Please include sample input, expected output, and your current output

Comment: Can you please show a sample part of the text file?

Comment: Besides, `except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print("UnicodeDecodeError")` would better be `except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            print("UnicodeDecodeError", e)` (please add the missing line breaks)

Comment: Why use `os.listdir()` without any filter? You are outputing your source code now...

Comment: I was just trying to get the data from a txt file, but pulling the data from a separate file an error that I didn't know how to deal with so I ignored it for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` does not modify the `F` variable. It returns a list of strings. You have to do something like:

```
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    try:
        F = open(filename, 'r+').read()
        print("Searching in " + filename)
        for token in F.split():
            if 'http' in token:
                print(token)
    except:
        print("Failed to open " + filename)
```

Comment: Okay, let me try that

Comment: It just fails to open. The file I'm trying to pull from has utf8 encoding

Comment: Fixed it, I just needed to change the way the file assigned it.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
F.split()
```

with

```
F= F.split()
for word in F:
   if 'http' in F:
    print(word.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Comes out with nothing

Comment: @IsaiahZeilman What does that mean? What does a following `print(F)` give? (Besides, that `F` would better be `f` or even `file_content`.)

Comment: @IsaiahZeilman I've updated the code snippet in my answer. This should make more sense to you.

Comment: If I only do print(F), it comes out with a UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: @IsaiahZeilman Sorry, I made a mistake in my edit. It should have been `word.encode()` instead of `F.encode()`